# Error en query SQL SERVER al intentar traer un campo

Tags: sql-server

Buenas tardes colegas en el trabajo donde estoy me colocaron a modificar un query de SQL SERVER donde debo traer un campo llamado ATR_DEPOSIT de una tabla llamada ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION, el campo PRIMARY KEY de esta tabla es ATR_IDENTITY_CODE, suena muy sencillo lo se, pero al intentar traerlo me salen diferentes errores dependiendo donde coloque ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_DEPOSIT
Alguno sabe como solucionar esto ? de ante mano muchas Gracias.

Este es el query que funciona muy bien sin yo intentar traer dicho campo:

```
      SELECT 0 COMMENTS,'PREVIOUS BALANCE' AS ACO_NAME,1 AS ATR_IDENTITY_CODE, 
  'PREVIOUS BALANCE' AS ATR_DESCRIPTION, '' AS BAN_NAME, '' AS BAC_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  9834.0000 AS ATR_DEBIT, 5468.0000 AS ATR_CREDIT,
  CONVERT(DATETIME,'4/6/2018') AS ATR_DATETIME,
  '' AS ATR_DEPOSIT_IMAGE_PATH,
  11 AS ATR_ACCOUNTING_CONCEPT, 4366.0000 AS TOTAL, CONVERT(DATETIME,'4/6/2018') AS ATR_DATE_POSTED,
  'NO' AS AGING_STATUS , '0' as ATR_DEBIT_NATIONAL_CURRENCY , '0' as ATR_CREDIT_NATIONAL_CURRENCY,
  '0' AS BALANCE_NATIONAL_CURRENCY
  UNION SELECT isnull(
      (SELECT COUNT (ATM_ACCOUNTING) FROM ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION_MESSAGE
      WHERE ATM_ACCOUNTING = ATR_IDENTITY_CODE ) ,0)
      COMMENTS , ACCOUNTING_CONCEPT.ACO_NAME AS ACO_NAME,
      ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_IDENTITY_CODE AS ATR_IDENTITY_CODE,
      ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_DESCRIPTION AS ATR_DESCRIPTION,
      BANK.BAN_NAME AS BAN_NAME,
      BANK_ACCOUNT.BAC_ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS BAC_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
      ATR_DEBIT, ATR_CREDIT, ATR_DATETIME,ATR_DEPOSIT_IMAGE_PATH, ATR_ACCOUNTING_CONCEPT,
      ISNULL(
        (SELECT SUM(A.ATR_DEBIT - A.ATR_CREDIT)
        FROM ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION A 
        WHERE A.ATR_ACCOUNTING_GROUP = 'O461' AND A.ATR_DATETIME <= ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_DATETIME
        AND A.ATR_ACCOUNTING_CONCEPT <> 11 AND ATR_STATUS = 'A'),0) AS TOTAL, 
        ATR_DATE_POSTED,
        IIF(ATR_CREDIT_STATUS IS NULL AND ATR_DEBIT_STATUS IS NULL, 'NO', 'YES') AS AGING_STATUS, 
        ATR_DEBIT_NATIONAL_CURRENCY, ATR_CREDIT_NATIONAL_CURRENCY ,
        (ATR_DEBIT_NATIONAL_CURRENCY - ATR_CREDIT_NATIONAL_CURRENCY) AS BALANCE_NATIONAL_CURRENCY
        FROM ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION
          INNER JOIN ACCOUNTING_CONCEPT
            ON ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_ACCOUNTING_CONCEPT = ACCOUNTING_CONCEPT.ACO_IDENTITY_CODE
          LEFT OUTER JOIN BANK
            ON ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_BANK = BANK.BAN_CODE
          LEFT OUTER JOIN BANK_ACCOUNT
            ON ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_BANK_ACCOUNT = BANK_ACCOUNT.BAC_CODE
        WHERE ATR_ACCOUNTING_GROUP = 'O461' AND ATR_STATUS = 'A'
        AND ATR_DATETIME >= CAST('4/6/2018 00:00:00.001' AS DATETIME)
        AND ATR_DATETIME <= CAST('4/13/2018 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME)ORDER BY ATR_DATETIME
```

Comment: Para responder a tu pregunta habría que saber en qué contexto debería aparecer el campo. La consulta es compleja y su identación no es que ayude mucho a comprenderla. ¿Quizá antes de la primera `UNION`... algo así:  `...   '0' AS BALANCE_NATIONAL_CURRENCY,  ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION.ATR_DEPOSIT  UNION SELECT isnull( ... `

Comment: Cristian, no hay forma que se te pueda ayudar, dices que cuando modificas la consulta se produce un error, pero no nos dices cual es el error ni tampoco nos muestras la consulta que dá el error. Solo te puedo comentar que si agregas un campo veas de hacerlo en todos los select´s del UNION, y además revisa si esto lo estás insertando en una tabla, de declarara la nueva columna en el insert. Suerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo Colegas, ya solucioné el error, gracias a todos los que comentaron e intentaron ayudarme, la solución era muy fácil, pero por mi ignorancia desconocia bien como funciona un UNION, cuando hay un UNION debe haber la misma cantidad de campos, en el mismo orden y del mismo tipo a ambos lados del UNION (Se que muchos ya lo sabian pero otros no lo sabiamos):

El query tiene un primer SELECT ............ y un  UNION SELECT. solo tenia que agregar el campo ATR_DEPOSIT en el primer SELECT y en el segundo SELECT que va después del UNION, ambos en la misma posición de cada SELECT..